# Xcode Accessibility Inspector not showing hit area

Tags: ios, xcode, accessibility, accessibility-inspector

I'm having a problem with Accessibility Inspector that since I installed XCode 12, my accessibility inspector stopped working like it was with xcode 11. I don't know if it is related to the newest simulators or the xcode itself.

Clicking on the "crosshair" button on accessibility inspector no longer light up the current hit area for the element.

[image]

*sample image

After upgrading to xcode 12, the green hit area is no longer appearing to me.

Comment: I always run into this issue too. I searched around and it seems like it's a bug.

Comment: Eventually I settled to using my real phone to test accessibility. You can [add a shortcut](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204390) to trigger VoiceOver with a triple-home button click.

Comment: I was afraid this would be a real bug 